# SSMS SQL Server grid not showing all of text

Tags: sql-server, ssms

When I execute a SQL query within SSMS, a grid of results is returned. This grid defaults to displaying a small portion of text. I am able to resize the grid to show all of the text. How would I force the grid to show all of the text without requiring resizing?

Comment: Make the column name really long

Comment: @SteveC Works! Wish SSMS did not require preposterous workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server Management Studio has no options regarding the size of the grid output window. The grid output window opens with its default size for every new query tab.

The only related options I could find are under Tools > Options... > Query Results > SQL Server > Results to Grid. These options do not include grid or window sizes.

[image: SSMS grid options]

---

If you want to switch to text output, select the text output option on the "SQL Editor" toolbar or press the shortcut `Ctrl`+`T`.

[image: SSMS SQL Editor toolbar]

Comment: Thanks. How would I send results to text. I chose the option, but still going to grid?